# How do I add a procedural "clouds" pattern to objects?

Tags: texturing, node-editor

How do I add a procedural "clouds" pattern to objects?

I want effect exactly like this

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please be so kind and describe in more detail what you want to do here. It would be helpful if you could describe what exactly your goal is and show that with sufficient high quality images. The image is a bit small, and it's hard to see what this is actually about. Try to formulate your question in such a way that it contains all the necessary information for a focused answer. Thank you!

Comment: As it stands, from the illustration, this could be a lighting effect, or a texture on the model, as suggested by [Callmepro](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/281803/35559)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start with a **Noise Texture** into a **Colorramp** into the **Base Colour** input.

Depending on the look you're going for you may want to also connect it to your roughness.

If you can't get the look you're after with the Noise Texture controls try some of the other available textures.

[image]

[image]